# Error while creating the contract with ethereum in the initial tx

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-debugging, remix, invalid-opcode

I get this error when I try to create the contract with some ETH, but if I just click create without sending ether the contract is correctly deployed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor isn't `payable`.

Contract functions throw if Ether is sent and the function isn't explicitly marked `payable`. This helps prevent Ether from becoming marooned in contracts that weren't expecting it and have no withdraw function with which to get it back.

Since function `MyToken(` .... isn't `payable` the deployment itself fails with an exception when unwanted/unexpected Ether arrives.

You can resolve that with

```
function MyToken(...) payable {}
```

I see you have a `payable` fallback function so you could deploy the contact, then send funds to the contract address.

On first look, this contract appears to have no way to recover Ether sent to it, so it's effectively burned once transferred. This does indeed show that it's important for designers to consider how Ether moves in and out and why it's desirable to prevent unwanted receipts.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answer; I have another question for you: why the fallback function is called even though I send 0 ether at the start?

Comment: You posted this as an answer but it is actually a new question. You will get better answers if you post it as a new question.